# Gcloud components not being installed on local machine

Tags: bash, google-kubernetes-engine, zsh, gcloud, google-cloud-shell

I'm trying to use the `gcloud components install` to install `anthoscli` and `kpt` on my local machine but eventhough they are installed, everytime I try to run them as commands (e.g `anthoscli apply`) my zsh shell says there's no such command (eventhough `kubectl` works fine).

I tried to just to find where the component binaries are installed and then point to them in my `.zshrc` file but I couldn't find anywhere online that points to their file directory. The components seem to work as normal in my google cloud shell but not locally; any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to search fot the command and include the directory in you $PATH variable.

To find the command `anthoscli` you should use the command:

`find -name "*anthoscli*" -type f /`

With the result, you can add the following line in your `~/.zshrc`:

`PATH="$PATH:<directory_found_in_previous_command>"`

Then simply "reload" your zsh configuration with:

`source ~/.zshrc`